# Where can i found a book that have problems with solutions

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I notice that i am very weak on solving math worded problems. Im currently a civil engineering in the philippines.  Are there books available that.focuses on word problem that contains also solutions? Specifically on differential calculus? Currently our topic is on optimization(application of calculus?). I just want to sharpen my skill on it. I hope you guys understand my question :)

Comment: Calculus: Problems and Solutions
A. Ginzburg. it has many problems, sequences, derivatives etc.

Comment: How about problems and solutions that focus only on optimization calculus?